# \textbf{} does not work

Tags: fonts, bold

When I write in `\gre` `\textbf{}` does not work, but when I write in `\lat` everything is in bold and I cannot convert it to normal with `{\normalfont  }`
I use an assignment template from ShareLatex:

```
%%% Template originaly created by Karol Kozioł (mail@karol-koziol.net) and modified for ShareLaTeX use

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

newcommand{\lat}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gre}{\selectlanguage{greek}}

\usepackage[
pdftitle={Math Assignment}, 
pdfauthor={Joe Doe, Some University},
colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,bookmarks=true,
bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,textcomp}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={210mm,297mm},
left=25mm,right=25mm,%
bindingoffset=0mm, top=20mm,bottom=20mm}


\linespread{1.3}

\newcommand{\linia}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}}

% custom theorems if needed
\newtheoremstyle{mytheor}
{1ex}{1ex}{\normalfont}{0pt}{\scshape}{.}{1ex}
{{\thmname{#1 }}{\thmnumber{#2}}{\thmnote{ (#3)}}}

\theoremstyle{mytheor}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}

% my own titles
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
\begin{center}
\vspace{2ex}
{\huge \textsc{\@title}}
\vspace{1ex}
\\
\linia\\
\@author \hfill \@date
\vspace{4ex}
\end{center}
}
\makeatother
%%%

% custom footers and headers
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
%\lfoot{Assignment \textnumero{} 5}
%\cfoot{}
%\rfoot{Page \thepage\ /\ \pageref*{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
%

%%%----------%%%----------%%%----------%%%----------%%%
```

For example `{\gre \textbf{Άσκηση}}` and `{\lat exercise}`

Comment: Check your log file for font warnings. Most likely some greek font variant is missing

Comment: Probably you don't have bold greek fonts, they are difficult to find

Comment: Further investigation results in `tgtermes` package overriding the standard greek font (I think LaTeX uses `cbgreek-complete`) which has bold

Comment: besides greek, why everything in english is shown in bold?

Comment: I don't have this behaviour: please extend your code sample including your usage of the `\lat` command.

Comment: I see you've accepted my answer. I'm glad that you aren't bound to a specific font (it helps `:)`). Anyway, I wish you plenty of fun hours with LaTeX!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really know if `tgtermes` even *has* a bold variant of Greek font (if so, you're better off with the `computer modern` variant, as searching for the right templates of such peculiar fonts is pretty much the definition of masochism). Since you didn't specify the necessity of a specific font, I think my answer should suffice. You will probably dislike the change of font, but when you see all the vast options that come with it (and would probably induce some errors when paired with other fonts) you might reconsider.

The code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\lat}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gre}{\selectlanguage{greek}}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

{\lat It works!} \\
{\lat \textbf{It works!}} \\
{\lat \textit{It works!}} \\
{\lat \textbf{\textit{It works!}}} \\\\
{\gre It works!} \\
{\gre \textbf{It works!}} \\
{\gre \textit{It works!}} \\
{\gre \textbf{\textit{It works!}}}

\end{document}
```

The result.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `tgtermes` package doesn't support Greek. You can use `tempora`, instead.

Please, avoid `\gre` defined in that fashion. I suggest two different macros that take an argument: `\greek{<text in Greek>}` and `\english{<text in English>}`.

In the example code I only left the necessary packages, add the others you need, but remember that (apart from some exceptions you aren't loading) `hyperref` must go last.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage{tempora}

% hyperref should go LAST
\usepackage[
  pdftitle={Math Assignment},
  pdfauthor={Joe Doe, Some University},
  colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,bookmarks=true,
  bookmarksopenlevel=2
]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\english}{\foreignlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\greek}{\foreignlanguage{greek}}

\begin{document}

Ελληνική είναι η προεπιλεγμένη γλώσσα \english{exercise}

\textbf{Ελληνική}

\end{document}
```

[image]